# Crontab for Codeigniter

Tags: cron

How to set crontab in Codeigniter? 
I just tried to set like this "*/1 * * * * php  http://10.3.0.43:86/workallocation"
workallocation routs to a controller function (this function is working on direct browser) But it not working on the crontab. Please help me.

Comment: you should wget on the link instead...